# How to start to use httpd with socket activation (systemd)?

Tags: systemd, apache-httpd

The apache httpd server is seldom needed on one of our small servers, so it would be nice to start it via socket activation by systemd (and later stopped it when no traffic occurred for some time). Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Reworded the above, and the edit timed out at 5 minutes. The practical effects may not be useful. A client needs to connect with a 'startup' command before making normal requests. The client does not know ahead of time whether httpd is up, so the startup command needs to be sent before any normal requests. The delay will be high. In real life, the spiders and bots of the world may keep apache up perpetually. The question could be reworded to allow for answers like 'use a light weight http server like lighthttpd and leave it always-up'.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Apache 2.5 with [mod_systemd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_systemd.html).

For older Apache releases, you may use [systemd-socket-proxyd(8)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-socket-proxyd.html) but this will not automatically stop the Apache service after a timeout.

Comment: This is actually implemented in the [server core](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/f8450023c14656f20e964e75afdb3a16f4f38430/server/listen.c#L296), not in [mod_systemd](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/f8450023c14656f20e964e75afdb3a16f4f38430/modules/arch/unix/mod_systemd.c). (So building mod_systemd for Apache 2.4 won't get you socket activation.)

Answer (score -1):

File:

```
httpd.socket
```

Content:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=80
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:80
#BindIPv6Only=ipv6-only
After=network.target
Requires=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Make sure the apache service is also called httpd.

Comment: this does not works because the port is not forwarded to httpd.service from httpd.socket